# Force user to start with 0 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here's my fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7htqdk7y/5/)
this directive controll if user add Repetitive number or not , i'm trying to add another feature , input must start with 0 . if not, alert a message .

```
var clean = val.replace(/(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){‌​‌​11,}|(9){11,}|(0){11,}/g, '') ;
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/7htqdk7y/6/) (new feature)

but i can't handle this !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex `/(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){‌​‌​11,}|(9){11,}|(0){11,}/` matches 11 or more consecutive identical digits. You can change it to `/([0-9])\1{10,}/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clean = val.replace(/(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){‌​11,}|(9){11,}|(^0)[0-9]{10,}/g, '') ;
```

is, I think, what you want to achieve. Check the last part:

```
(^0)[0-9]{10,}
```

checks that the value entered starts with 0

Comment: I think you meant `[^0][0-9]{10,}`. `[^0]` matches any character other than `0`; `(^0)` matches a `0`, but only at the start of the string. Remember that the parsing rules for regexes are completely different inside a character class: `^` means negation if it's in a character class, or start of the string (or line) if it's not. Even this will fail however - if it encounters a 12-digit phone number starting with `01` (for instance), it will match everything from `1` onwards. You could try using word boundary: `\b[^0][0-9]{10,}`.

Comment: thanks but with [^0][0-9]{10,} , as @David Knipe said .
thank you guys